# Analyzing Big-Oh Notation with nested If statements/method calls

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, methods, big-o

I'm having a bit of trouble fully grasping Big-Oh notation and while I saw some answers for If statements, I did not see anything with method calls within if/else statements.  I'm posting the relevant code below, the linear and binary searches are standard implementation (I could have used the Arrays class but chose to practice coding them myself).  Both precise and general Big Oh notation would be helpful.  I've made an attempt below.

```
public static int count(int[][] myArray, int query) 
{
    queryHits = 0;   -----> O(1)
    queryNumber++;   -----> O(1)
    int subArraymin; -----> O(1)
    int subArraymax;  ----> O(1)
    int foundIndex = -1; -> O(1)
    int j = 5000;    -----> O(1)


        for (int i = 0; i<5000; i++)        ------------>O(5000 * O(?)
        { 
            subArraymin = myArray[0][j];        -------> O(1)
            subArraymax = myArray[999][j];       ------> O(1)

            if (query >= subArraymin && query <= subArraymax)     ----> O(1?)
            {
                foundIndex = binarySearch(myArray,0 , 1000, query, j); -->O(5000?) * O(log n)

                if (foundIndex == -1)       --> O(1?)
                {
                //irrelevant code omitted 
                }
                else 
                {
                    linearSearch(myArray, query, foundIndex, j);    -----> O(5000?) * O(n)
                }
            }
            else //irrelevant code omitted
        }
        return queryHits;
        }
```

My main questions:
1. Are my if statements O(1) or O(n)?
2. I believe that my for loop is O(5000 * the body of the loop) but since I'm calling two different methods, do those methods' big oh's get multiplied first?

Thank you for any help/pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a flowchart of the code, especially the if branches and the loops.  This helps a lot.  Alternately, draw the appropriate flow lines on your code.

In this case, the function complexities get added, not multiplied, because they occur in linear sequence.  Loops are what multiply, as you've already noted in your "5000*" uses.

Thus, the complexity for the loop is 5000*(O(log n) + O(n)).  This reduces simply to O(n), since 5000, 1000, and the other incidentals are all scalar constants.  If the "5000" comes from some other in put parameter (which you would likely call "m"), then the algorithm is O(m*n).

How much of this makes sense to you so far?

Comment: I think all of that makes sense actually.  5000*(the big o of the body, in this case the methods).  I'm not 100% on the very last part though; I hard coded 5000 as I use it to loop through 5000 columns of a 2d array.  So would it be O(n) still in that case?

Comment: If this is an n*m array, then you have O(n*m) for this algorithm.
If the array is *always* no more than 5000 wide, then it's O(n).  Id the algorithm made to apply to an array of any width (that being "m")?

Comment: Okay, that makes then! So I guess in theory, the best thing to do would be to eliminate the linear search and modify the binary search to do the same work since O(n) dominates over O(log n).  Is that correct?